# Get request python as a string

Tags: python, html, request, get

I wanted to send a get request in python and return it as a string. I wanna eventually use that string as something later on. Also by default does python return it in json format?

```py
req = requests.get(server, auth=('user',"pass"))
```

Comment: If you're looking for a high-level wrapper, the `requests` library PyPi is decent.

Comment: Are you talking about the requests module? I'm pretty sure get returns a Response object, not json or a string (but you can obtain both from the Response object). Can you post your code?

Comment: i dont want it in json though, i just want a string.

Comment: code posted, Im unsure if id get it as a json, object or a string. I would like it as a string

Comment: What is the server's response? What does `print(req)` give you? What output are you getting, and what is your *desired* output?

Comment: `req.text` would do the job

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use [python requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Check the link, there are examples how you get json from response.

```
req = requests.get(server, auth=('user',"pass"))
req.json()
```

If you want it as string, use

```
req.text
```

Comment: but what if i want it as a string?

Comment: @TaimoorKhan use `req.text`, it will give you in string format what returned from response

Comment: please note that:
    type(req.json) is class 'dict' 
    type(req.json()) is class 'method'

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, instead of getting the response as text, it's more useful to get as bytes to parse it later (`.text` gives a decoded `.content`, so `req.text == req.content.decode(req.encoding)` is always true).

```py
req = requests.get(url)
req.content
```

It's especially useful to read data from web pages (in East or South Asian languages) that use a non-UTF-8 encoding such as ISO-8859-1 and you want to use a parser such as BeautifulSoup.

```py
BeautifulSoup(req.text)      # <---- gibberish
BeautifulSoup(req.content)   # <---- OK
```