# AWS Lambda Python3 How to return string instead of binary(default) CJK problem

Tags: python, encoding, python-requests, aws-lambda, cjk

I'm Building a Massive Crawler which AWS Lambda must be used for its speed.
But since i read data from lambda, it will double encode the non english text.

some like

`"b\'<!DOCTYPE html>\\\\r\\\\n<html lang=\\"ko\\">\\\\r\\\\n<head>\\\\r\\\\n\\\\t<title id=\\"browse_title\\">\\\\\'\\\\xec\\\\x8a\\\\x88\\\\xea\\\\xb0\\\\x80\\\\xeb\\\\xa7\\\\xa82\\\\\'`

code from lambda

```
def get_html(url):
    r = requests.request(url=url, method="GET")
    # r.encoding = 'euc-kr'

    return {
        "html": r.content
    }
```

Code from invoking lambda

```
def call_lambda_function():
    invoke_response = client.invoke(
        FunctionName="lambda_function_test",
        InvocationType="RequestResponse",
        Payload=json.dumps(payload)
    )
    data = invoke_response['Payload'].read()
    print(data)
```

output from invoking lambda

> b'{"html": "\r\n\r\n\r\n\t\'\uc288\uac00\ub9e82\' 7\uacf5\uc8fc
>   \uadfc\ud669 \uacf5\uac1c
>   \"\uc5f0\uae30\u00b7\uce74\uc774\uc2a4\ud2b8
>   \uc785\ud559\u00b7\u82f1 \ubc29\uc1a1\uc0ac \ud569\uaca9\" ....

adding `decode('my-encoding')` wont work. it will decode, but the decoded result is encoded string. (which is i said double encoded)

So! here is what i want.

i want to make lambda not return byte, but string object.

I wish there is a simple solution for that!

else I've tried for this.
`adding return str(return_target) to lambda function`
this will still return bytes

Comment: Have u tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32875241/get-request-python-as-a-string

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution.

add `json.dumps` to lambda
add `json.loads` to invoke result (after decoding)