# Python download multiple files within for loop

Tags: python, download, python-requests

I have a list of URLs, which direct to filings from the SEC (e.g., https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/18651/000119312509042636/d10k.htm)

My goal ist to write a for loop that opens the URLs, request the document and save it to a folder.
However, I need to be able to identify the documents later. Thats why I wanted to use "htps://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/**18651/000119312509042636**/d10k.htm" this filing-specific number as document name

```
directory = r"\Desktop\10ks"
for url in url_list:
    response = requests.get(url).content
    path = (directory + str(url)[40:-5] +".txt")
    with open(path, "w") as f:
        f.write(response)
    f.close()
```

But everytime, I get the following error message: filenotfounderror: [errno 2] no such file or directory:

I really hope you can help me out!!
Thanks

Comment: What is that `r` you have in directory?

Comment: @JuanBenitez. `r` before a string means a raw string so that the back-slashes are not treated as escape characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
import os
url_list = ["https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/18651/000119312509042636/d10k.htm"]
#Create the path Desktop/10ks/
directory = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop") + "\\10ks"
for url in url_list:
    #Get the content as string instead of getting it as bytes
    response = requests.get(url).text
    #Replace slash in filename with underscore
    filename = str(url)[40:-5].replace("/", "_")
    #print filename to check if it is correct
    print(filename)
    path = (directory + "\\" + filename +".txt")
    with open(path, "w") as f:
        f.write(response)
    f.close()
```

See comments.
I guess backslashes in filenames are not allowed, since

```
filename = str(url)[40:-5].replace("/", "\\")
```

gives me

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\user/Desktop\\10ks\\18651\\000119312509042636\\d10.txt'
```

See also:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser

[Get request python as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32875241/get-request-python-as-a-string)

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
for url in url_list:
    response = requests.get(url).content.decode('utf-8')
    path = (directory + str(url)[40:-5] +".txt").replace('/', '\\')
    with open(path, "w+") as f:
        f.write(response)
    f.close()
```

the path that you were build was something like this `\\Desktop\\10ks18651/000119312509042636/d10.txt` I suppose you are working on windows for those backslashes, anyways you just need to replace the slashes that were coming in the url to backslashes.

Another thing, `write` receives a string, because of that you need to decode your response that is coming in bytes to string.

I hope this helps you!